# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Im kinda new to cocos2d and objective-c in general so bear with me. I got a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in my code, so I did what I usually do, and turned on NSZombies. This usually spits out something useful, but this time spit out nothing, and the program didn't crash.

The crash comes during the second line of the update function in my enemy class

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)delta{
    speed = SPEED;
    angleToTargetInRadians = -atan2((self.position.y-target.position.y),(self.position.x-target.position.x));
```

speed and angleToTargetInRadians are both doubles defined in the header file.

The crash happens when the 4th or 5th enemy is killed.

```
- (void)die {
//give the player some points
[((AppController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate) addScore:POINTVALUE];
//make the shattered sprite
ShatteredSprite * blownUpShip = [ShatteredSprite shatterWithSprite:self piecesX:4 piecesY:4 speed:3 rotation:.02];
//add it to the layer
[self.parent addChild:blownUpShip];

//set the position and momentum and scale
[blownUpShip setVx: Vx];
[blownUpShip setVy: Vy];
[blownUpShip setScale:self.scale];
[blownUpShip setPosition:self.position];
[blownUpShip setRotation:self.rotation];

//get rid of the old ship
[self removeSelf];
}

- (void)removeSelf {
//remove self from array
NSMutableArray * enemies = [((AppController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate) Enemies];
[enemies removeObject:self];

[super die];
}
```

[super die] is just

```
[self removeFromParentAndCleanup:FALSE];
```

any help is appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Any reason for not calling `[self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];` instead?

Comment: @ssantos thanks for responding! I just tried that, and it calls another bad access on [child setParent:nil]; in -(void) detachChild:(CCNode *)child cleanup:(BOOL)doCleanup in the CCNode.m file.

Comment: ARC or no ARC? Have you enabled global exception breakpoint in Xcode (helps to see the actual offending line)? You should do cleanup:YES because that'll kill off any remaining actions and scheduled selectors of the enemy will keep running, and the cleanup method isn't called either. There's only one reason not to cleanup, that's when you immediately want to re-add the node to another parent.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D no ARC. I just tried it with the global exception breakpoint, and it didn't stop the game before it crashed. Thanks for your time!

Comment: my guess: over-released object (self)

Comment: that was it! thanks! I released the enemy ship once when I created it. the only reason the ship stayed around at all was because the Enemies array had a copy of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use the ship object that is passed into `ShatteredSprite` initialiser within `ShatteredSprite`?

It seems to me that you are doing something like this (note that this is just a guess):

1. initialise a new Sprite for your enemy ship (probably autoreleased)
2. add this sprite as a child to a node and into enemies mutable array
3. when the ship is destroyed, you initialise a new Sprite (`ShatteredSprite` with the ship sprite)
4. remove the ship sprite from parent node AND from the enemies array --> at this time, there is no retained reference and thus the ship is ready to be released.

Therefore, are you using your ship sprite in `ShatteredShip` without retaining it?

You might find something useful with the Analyze tool from the Product menu in Xcode.